# Flask not working, tried fixes from other questions none have worked

Tags: python, flask

when i try and run my flask site i get the error

```
E:\Database>flaskSite.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Database\flaskSite.py", line 1, <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

but flask is installed as when i type pip install flask it shows

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to up
ib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to up
thon34\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to up
on34\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to up
c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to up
n34\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
```

My code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Oops sorry let me update it, put the wrong thing in

Comment: Include the code that you've written to get to that point.

Comment: What is the output of `from sys import path; print(path)` for `flaskSite.py` (you can put it right before `app.run`, indented to the same level)?

Comment: C:\Users\sturge95\Desktop\Web Assignment 2>flaskSite.py
['C:\\Users\\sturge95\\Desktop\\Web Assignment 2', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.
5\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\Pyt
hon 3.5\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\
lib\\site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sturge95\Desktop\Web Assignment 2\flaskSite.py", line 3, in <mo
dule>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ImportError: No module named 'flask'

C:\Users\sturge95\Desktop\Web Assignment 2>

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell , but your python is on C disk and you are running it from E disk, make sure that they are running same version of python.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said:

1. Check if the version of python you start is the same as you have installed the package into. On my system `python` starts 2.7.8, but for development I use 3.4.2. To check, run python from command line, then do the same thing from your script.

   ```
   import sys
   print(sys.version)
   ```
2. Compare the path settings (you will also see the version here):

   ```
   import sys
   print(sys.path)
   ```
3. Your pip-log is corrupted - you missed a bit when you copy/pasted. If you paste the complete log it might be visible where your library path is..

Summary: create a script as follows, then run it and paste results here:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)
```

Thanks for the additional output (I can't comment yet).

Your PIP seems to point to python 3.4, but the lib path you have provided is for 3.5. You have two versions installed.

You can change the default association for your .py file:

https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

From windows command line, run:

```
ftype Python.File=PATH_TO_CORRECT_BIN\python.exe "%1" %*
```